# Apache Cordova Camera Plugin on Windows Phone (Universal) - Error: Access denied

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova

ive created a simple cordova app and test the camera plugin on windows phone. 
My Camera Plugin has version 1.2.0

I can choose pictures from the photo library, but if i try to get a picture from the camera the following error appears

[image]

Any idears what i can do?

THX & Regards!

Comment: Interesting, I got the same error and I can determine this is cause because a fileIO.readBufferAsync call will be raised when we set the destinationType other than FILE_URI and NATIVE_URI. I just tried to test with the Microsoft official sample and got the same issue. https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/File-access-sample-d723e597

Comment: I will try to find out what happens and update here.

Comment: OK.my mistake. It does work in the MS official sample. And I think I found a workaround.

Comment: Hello Alan, THX for your Help. Can you tell me your Workaround? Regards

Answer (score 3):

This issue has been fixed with commit [110b3b3](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera/commit/110b3b33886ba2fff9827f69a08660d660a22e77). Hope it helps!

Comment: If you're upgrading to version 2.0.0 you will need to update your cordova-android platform to 5.0.0+

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because the picture object created is blocked by something so that the fileIO.readBufferAsync cannot work with that object. Based on the test result on MS official sample, I checked the code in the file `plugins/cordova-plugin-camera/src/windows/CameraProxy.js` , and I found there is no big difference from the MS official sample. The only one I found is the file created and read in one call in CameraProxy.js, but in MS sample, they are in two calls.

And after I get the following code changed, it starts working. Please find the following code around line 692 in the file I mentioned above:

```js
fileIO.readBufferAsync(picture).done(function(buffer) {
                    var strBase64 =encodeToBase64String(buffer);
                    picture.deleteAsync().done(function() {
                        successCallback(strBase64);
                    }, function(err) {
                        errorCallback(err);
                    });
                }, errorCallback);
```

And change it to the following code:

```js
var tempFolder = getAppData().temporaryFolder;
                tempFolder.getFileAsync(picture.name).done(
                    function (file) {
                        // If file exists. 
                        var a = file;
                        fileIO.readBufferAsync(picture).done(function (buffer) {
                            var strBase64 = encodeToBase64String(buffer);
                            picture.deleteAsync().done(function () {
                                successCallback(strBase64);
                            }, function (err) {
                                errorCallback(err);
                            });
                        }, errorCallback);
                    },
                    function (err) {
                        
                    }
                )
```

Answer (score 0):

i change the code in the CameraProxy.js to

```
 var tempFolder = getAppData().temporaryFolder;
            tempFolder.getFileAsync(picture.name).done(
                function(file) {
                    // If file exists. 
                    var a = file;

                    fileIO.readBufferAsync(picture).done(function(buffer) {
                        var strBase64 = encodeToBase64String(buffer);
                        picture.deleteAsync().done(function() {
                            successCallback(strBase64);
                        }, function(err) {
                            errorCallback(err);
                        });
                    }, errorCallback);

                },
                function(err) {

                }
            );
```

and got the same error.

Here is my typescript that i call to access the camera

```
export function getPictureFromCamera() {
        navigator.camera.getPicture((data: string) => {
            $('#image').attr("src", "data:image/jpeg;base64," + data);
        }, error => {
            $('#error').text(error);
        },
        {
            quality: 100,
            destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
            sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
            allowEdit: true,
            encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
            targetWidth: 300,
            targetHeight: 300,
            saveToPhotoAlbum: false
        });
    }
```

Another workaround for me is that i can call the camera from the photolibrary

[image]

This works for me, because after i accept the picture i'm back in my app code.

Regards